# Elisp - adding multiple insertions to buffer-undo-list (saving undo information)

Tags: emacs, elisp

**Update: my original question was answered, but I'd like to know the more general approach - how can I define multiple operations which will be undone with a single C-/.**

I'm trying to write a function which will automatically insert TODO comment into my code. I want this function to have an "undo option".

I figured out how to add a mark to buffer-undo-list:

```
(setq buffer-undo-list (cons (point) buffer-undo-list))
```

This allows me to return the point to the position from which this function was executed (if I decide to undo).

My question is: how can I add multiple insertions to buffer-undo-list? What I mean is that there are multiple (insert str) statements in my function, but I want to undo all of them together with a single C-/ (if I decide to undo).

I tried to copy exactly from other function which has this property, but this didn't work out. The code below is what I have now:

```
(defun insert-todo ()
  "Appednd 'TODO username: date - ' at the end of line and set point 
to where this string ends"
  (interactive)

  (setq buffer-undo-list (cons (point) buffer-undo-list))   ;; save the point for undo
  (save-excursion 
    (end-of-line)
    (setq eol (point))
    (let ((buffer-undo-list t)) ;; do not record following commands for undo    
      (insert " " comment-start (save-excursion comment-end))   
      (insert (format " TODO %s: " (getenv "USER")) (format-time-string "%d.%m.%Y") " - ") 
      (setq buffer-undo-list (cons (cons eol (point)) buffer-undo-list))))
  (end-of-line)
  )
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. What does "inserted text" stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't touch `buffer-undo-list`.  It's automatically updated as part of `insert` so it should "just work" without you doing anything special.

The way it works is that instead of inventing new formats of undo enties that combine various modifications, the undo-log is sprinkled with boundaries and when you undo, all the entries between two boundaries get undone "in one step".  A boundary is normally added after each iteration of the read-eval-print loop, so in 99% of cases, it "just works".

Comment: I don't want each insert being pushed into buffer-undo-list separately - I want all these inserts to be treated as a single entry.
Furthermore, now I want to know how to do this independently of this special example - what if instead of just inserts I'd write a function which uses other commands as well?

Comment: What happens when you try removing all tampering with `buffer-undo-list` in your function? Does `undo` really consider both `(insert ...)`s to be separate? I tried doing this on my setup and everything seems to work fine: all modifications are undone together.

Comment: Indeed, not touching this variable produces the desired result. I should've checked this before posting the previous comment. Sorry.
But, I still want to know the answer. Suppose, for example, that I'd want to undo just the second insert - how this can be accomplished?

Comment: @VasiliyZukanov: Then you need to add a boundary explicitly with `undo-boundary`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled upon this very problem, and it seems that putting `(undo-auto-amalgamate)` at the beginning of my command and an explicit `(undo-boundary)` at the end does the trick.